# How can I use unit of work pattern with generic repository pattern in my ASP.NET Core Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, unit-of-work

There are many examples on the internet about the use of unit of work and generic repository together, but I couldn't find exactly how to apply the unit of work repository pattern to my own project. Because everyone did it differently.

Actually, I set up the unit of work structure, but I don't quite understand how I can use it in my own project? How can I apply the unit of work repository I made to my own project? Can you help me with this? Can you tell me if I have a mistake? This is how I saw the unit of work repository on the internet and implemented it.

First of all, if I just talk about my project, my project is an ASP.NET Core Web API project and basically a 3-layer structure:

1. API layer. I have controllers in the API layer.
2. Second is the business layer. The business layer only serves to communicate with the data access layer.
3. The third layer is the data access layer, in this layer I do the database operations, such as adding, deleting, updating.

I'm doing these with the generic repository. As an example, I am sharing some of my code below.

I just shared category as an example, but I have more than one class like category.

API layer - `CategoriesController`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class categoriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private ICategoryService category_service;
    DatabaseContext c = new DatabaseContext();

    public categoriesController(ICategoryService category_service)
    {
        this.category_service = category_service;
    }
   
    [HttpGet("getall")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok(await category_service.TGetAll());
    }

    [HttpGet("getbyid/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdCategory(int id)
    {
        var category = await category_service.TGetById(id);

        if (category != null)
        {
            return Ok(category);  // 200 ok
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound(); //404 not found
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Category category)
    {
        var result =  category_service.TAdd(category);

        if (result != null)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }

        return BadRequest(result);
    }
}
```

Business layer - `CategoryManager`:

```
public class CategoryManager:ICategoryService
{
    ICategoryDal _categoryDal;
       
    public CategoryManager(ICategoryDal _cateogoryDal)
    {
        this._categoryDal = _cateogoryDal;
    }

    public async Task<List<Category>> TGetAll()
    {
        return await _categoryDal.GetListAll();
    }

    public async Task<Category> TGetById(int id)
    {
        return await _categoryDal.GetByID(id);
    }

    public async Task TAdd(Category entity)
    {
        await _categoryDal.Insert(entity);
    }

    public async Task TDelete(Category entity) 
    {
        await _categoryDal.Delete(entity);
    }

    public async Task TUpdate(Category entity)
    {
        await _categoryDal.Update(entity);
    }
}
```

Data Access layer - `CategoryRepository`:

```
public class CategoryRepository : GenericRepository<Category>, ICategoryDal
{
}
```

`GenericRepository`:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericDal<T> where T : class
{
    protected DatabaseContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        dbContext = context;
    }

    public async Task Delete(T t)
    {
        dbContext.Remove(t);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
     
    public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return dbContext.Set<T>()
                        .Where(expression)
                        .AsNoTracking();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetByID(int id)
    {
        return await dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetListAll()
    {
        return await dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetListAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return await dbContext.Set<T>()
                              .Where(filter)
                              .ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task Insert(T t)
    {
        await dbContext.AddAsync(t);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Update(T t)
    {
        var updatedEntity = dbContext.Entry(t);
        updatedEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`UnitOfWork`:

```
public class UnitOfWorkRepository : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _dbContext;
    private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;
    private bool _disposed;

    public UnitOfWorkRepository(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public bool BeginNewTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            _transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }

        this._disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public IGenericDal<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new GenericRepository<T>(_dbContext);
    }

    public bool RollBackTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
            _transaction = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        var transaction = _transaction != null ? _transaction : _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

        using (transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                // Context boş ise hata fırlatıyoruz
                if (_dbContext == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Context is null");
                }

                // SaveChanges metodundan dönen int result ı yakalayarak geri dönüyoruz.
                int result = _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                // Sorun yok ise kuyruktaki tüm işlemleri commit ederek bitiriyoruz.
                transaction.Commit();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Hata ile karşılaşılır ise işlemler geri alınıyor 
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw new Exception("Error on SaveChanges ", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`IUnitOfWork`:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    bool BeginNewTransaction();
    bool RollBackTransaction();
    IGenericDal<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This is all kind of unnecessary since Entity Framework already implements both the generic repository and unit of work patterns. All you are doing is adding a less efficient layer of abstraction on top of that. The repository and unit of work patterns are intended for cases where you don't have a good ORM abstraction over your data store. Many ORMs already full implement them.

Comment: It might be true. But I need to implement it in this project.

Comment: Why? Dont blindly follow patterns. You bring unnecessary  complexity

Comment: yes I understand. However, unit of work is a desired structure in this project. I set up the structure in this way, maybe unit of work may be unnecessary in this structure, but since this project is a homework, I need to set up the unit of work structure. You're right, if there was no homework, I wouldn't have done it personally. Secondly, why is unit of work unnecessary in this structure? What did you mean when you said that the entity framework already implements the generic repository and the unit of work, could you explain in a little more detail?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the source in the link.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/repository-unit-work-patterns-net-core-dimitar-iliev/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33178269)